# CD spectra of Porin molecules?

Tags: spectroscopy

Can anyone please help me how will the CD spectra or graph of porin molecule look like. Porin molecule has 14 beta plated structures joined by some random coil, but it's very confusing to draw it. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! First, please define abbreviations (i.e. CD). Second, we encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For example, if I search with your title I get numerous hits to papers including [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2323856/).——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

CD (circular dichroism) spectrum of porin will look like CD spectra of most beta-sheet-reach proteins. You can look, for example, [paper on PorB protein](http://www.jbc.org/content/273/39/25329) (Minetti et al, JBC, 1998) where authors present CD spectra of one of porines:

Circular dichroism spectra of recombinant PorB class 3 protein as a function of SDS. Standard solutions of PorB rclass 3 protein (1.0 mg/ml) dialyzed against a buffer comprised of 10 mM sodium phosphate and 0.05% zwittergent 3-14 and incubated with varying concentrations of SDS (0-1%) at 25.0 °C for 24 h prior to spectroscopic analysis. Far UV CD spectra are recorded for rclass 3 in the absence of SDS (solid circles) and at the following SDS concentrations: 0.15% (open triangles), 0.25% (solid squares), 0.30% (open diamonds), 0.40% (solid triangles), 0.45% (open circles), 0.50% (solid diamonds), and 1.0% (open squares).

[image: Circular dichroism spectra of recombinant PorB class 3 protein as a function of SDS. Standard solutions of PorB rclass 3 protein (1.0 mg/ml) dialyzed against a buffer comprised of 10 mM sodium phosphate and 0.05% zwittergent 3-14 and incubated with varying concentrations of SDS (0-1%) at 25.0 °C for 24 h prior to spectroscopic analysis. Far UV CD spectra are recorded for rclass 3 in the absence of SDS (solid circles) and at the following SDS concentrations: 0.15% (open triangles), 0.25% (solid squares), 0.30% (open diamonds), 0.40% (solid triangles), 0.45% (open circles), 0.50% (solid diamonds), and 1.0% (open squares).]